# Homebrew PHP5.5 failures OSX

Tags: php, macos, apache, laravel, mcrypt

I am on OS X 10.9.5.

I installed Php 5.5 via homebrew and also the PHP 5.5 mcrypt extension, php55 and php55-mcrypt in homebrew. In order to enable php5 in apache, I added this to /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

```
LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/opt/php55/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

I'm using Laravel and need the Mcrypt extension, so I added this to /usr/local/php/5.5/php.ini

```
extension=mcrypt.so
```

In order to force the terminal to use the proper PHP version, 5.5, rather than the 5.4 the computer shipped with, I renamed /usr/bin/php to /usr/bin/php-old, and now the terminal falls back to /usr/local/bin/php, which is the version 5.5 that I'd like to use. Now, I am getting the following error in the terminal whenever I do anything in php from terminal.

```
[Sat Sep 20 16:32:12 2014] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.17/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/mcrypt.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.17/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/mcrypt.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
```

Any ideas on how this happened or where I went wrong? I'm getting discouraged by this OSX development server setup and considering just giving in and installing a dual-booted Ubuntu Partition. I was hoping to leverage OSX's unix base, but it has been a nightmare to setup the dev server so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have messed with homebrew since your PHP is looking for files in Cellar. Run "which php" and check which PHP is actually running and run "php --ini" to make sure you edited the right PHP configuration.

The easiest way to get a proper running PHP is to install it from Homebrew and add that to your PATH.

Comment: Which php returns '/usr/local/bin/php'. php --ini returns 'Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/5.5
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/5.5/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d/ext-mcrypt.ini'. This is preceded by the same warning 'PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.17/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/mcrypt.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.17/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-201212...